# Output for default in switchcase

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have this code and it works perfectly but this. When I try to run the code and fill up the form with Deployed case, the notification saying **The Monitor is not available for use.** is not come out. The system still saved the data and no pop out displayed even when I choose the default case. Is there any wrong with my code ?

Here is part of my code :

```
switch ($DeskMonSN) {
case "Available":
    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"0; URL=EditDesktop.php? 
Desk_SN=$DeskSN\">";
    break;
case "Standby Unit":
    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"0; URL=EditDesktop.php?
Desk_SN=$DeskSN\">";
    break;
case "Deployed":
    echo ('<script type="text/javascript">alert("The Monitor is not available      
for use.")</script>');
    break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the echo command in case "Deployed" should be on the one line. But I dont know if it is your problem. If the echo command with the alert would be in one line in your php editor everything will work fine.

Or you can try this in case "Deployed":

```
echo ('<script type="text/javascript">');
echo ('alert("The Monitor is not available for use.")');
echo ('</script>');
```

T. B.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as it should. Make sure you pass the string "Deployed" with the same case

You might try this and try to debug the problem :

```
$DeskMonSN = "Deployed";
switch ($DeskMonSN) {
case "Available":
    //.............
```